# Why Julia is slower than MATLAB?

Tags: julia

I just wrote this very simple function to test the performance of both Julia and MATLAB. I just noticed that the execution time is significantly lower in MATLAB. Here is the simple code:

MATLAB:

```
tic

aa = 0;

for loop =1:1e6

       aa = aa+loop;

end

toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.004628 seconds.

Julia:

```
function sum_test(a)

    for i = 1:1e6
        a = a + i
    end

    return a
end
```

Elapsed time is 0.093886155s: 93 milliseconds.

I also wrote a function in Julia to avoid using global variables which improved the performance but it is still significantly slower than MATLAB. Can someone help me to understand this please?

Comment: Such a short benchmark is meaningless. It should run for several seconds at least. Consider also using [scilab](https://www.scilab.org/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's impossible to say without seeing how you are timing your Julia code. However the most likely explanation is that you are timing both compile time and execution time. The Julia and MatLab compiler's behave quite differently. When you write a new function in Julia it is compiled the first time you use it. Consequently, the first execution of it will be quite slow, but all subsequent calls are fast. To get around this, if you are benchmarking Julia, it is recommended you use the `BenchmarkTools` package. On my (not particularly special) machine:

```
function sum_test(a)
    for i = 1:1e6
        a = a + i
    end
    return a
end
using BenchmarkTools
@btime sum_test(1)
```

produces the following output:

```
julia> @btime sum_test(1)
  2.135 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

so roughly 2 milliseconds which is about twice as fast as your MatLab run.

But can we do better? We most certainly can. MatLab tends to treat all numbers like they are double precision floats, and so one doesn't tend to think too much about the type of one's numbers when coding in MatLab. In Julia, this is not the case. In this example, you've specified the upper bound of your loop as `1e6`. Note that:

```
julia> typeof(1e6)
Float64
```

Aha! You probably didn't intend your loop variable to be a `Float64`, but rather wanted it to be an integer. So what happens when we change it? Try running this:

```
function sum_test(a)
    for i = 1:1000000
        a = a + i
    end
    return a
end
using BenchmarkTools
@btime sum_test(1)
```

Now this outputs:

```
julia> @btime sum_test(1)
  1.208 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Yes, you've read that correctly. It took 1.2 nanoseconds, or roughly 6 orders of magnitude faster than MatLab.

So what is going on? In the case where the loop upper bound is an integer, the Julia compiler is smart enough to realize that it doesn't actually need to run the loop in order to correctly work out the result. Because of the nature of the algorithm being performed the answer can be determined with a single formula, which the compiler has done for you. In other words, the Julia compiler optimized away the entire loop!

Comment: Hah, `@code_llvm sum_test(1)` is `%1 = add i64 %0, 500000500000; ret i64 %1`. This is awesome.

Comment: I did what you suggested and I was able to generate the same results but it raises a few other questions for me:
1. I was using the following to measure the elapsed time:
tick()
Sum_test(1)
tock 

which gave me this: [ Info:          0.083350786s: 83 milliseconds

so why it is different to measure time using @bitme and tick-tock? And in the cases that I need to measure the elapse time of a chunk of code, what should I do?

Comment: 2. I noticed that when I use btime, it takes a few seconds(!!) to display the output which is : 3.176 ms (1 allocation: 16 bytes). Then it doesn’t give you the feeling that the execution time is in order of milliseconds. I am asking this because I want to report the measured time of my code and I am not sure if using btime can convince the people after they ran my code.
3. I noticed that your output is different from mine, since you report (0 allocation: 0 bytes) but I get (1allocation: 16bytes), why?

Comment: `@btime` runs your function many, many times (probably thousands of times), and calculates statistics. `tic`/`toc` are not suitable for measuring the execution times of very short functions, because the measurements will be very noisy, and may also include compilation times, occasional OS hiccups or garbage collection. So don't use `tic`/`toc` or `@time` to measure execution times of short functions, use `@btime` or `@benchmark`. The same for Matlab and Python: don't use `tic`/`toc`, use the `timeit` function, which is similar to `@btime`.

Comment: @DNF I'm assuming that if your function actually takes several minutes per execution, btime will only have to run it once to get a reasonable benchmark time?

Comment: The number of executions depend on how long it takes to execute, but I would at least expect it to execute twice (I'm not sure exactly how that works).

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I'm no dev on `BenchmarkTools`, but I have used `@btime` on longer routines before, and it still appears to run the routine quite a few times. In other words, if you're using it on a 2-minute routine, you could be waiting for a while to get the result, although anecdotally probably only on the order of many minutes, rather than many hours.

Comment: @Akon I believe DNF has answered most of your questions about how `@btime` works, but the short answer is yes, all Julia users will strongly prefer to see results from `@btime` than any other method of timing. Also, be aware of an implication of this: Julia really shines in cases where you have short functions that get called many times, rather than having one long routine that you only ever call once. MatLab on the other hand tends to encourage the "one long routine" style of programming.

Comment: @Akon Regarding allocations in your output, what version Julia are you running? My results were generated on v1.4.2. There's a lot of work being done on the compiler, so timings and allocations can change quite a bit between versions.